# Port map if there are many ports

Tags: vhdl

For example, I have a component (e.g. a multiplexer with 128 inputs and 1 output). I want to instantiate this component. So I need a port mapping for these 128 inputs. My question is: is there any easier way to do 128 ports' mapping instead of writing 128 statements?
Thanks a lot!

Suppose we have this component:

```
component MUX_1bit is   
port(   

    data0       : IN STD_LOGIC ;
    data1       : IN STD_LOGIC ;
    ......
    data127     : IN STD_LOGIC ;
    select      : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 DOWNTO 0);
    result      : OUT STD_LOGIC);
end component;
```

Now if I want to instantiate it,

```
myMUX : MUX_1bit port map(  
    data0 => signal0,  
    data1 => signal1,  
   ..................
);
```

Is there any easier way instead of repeating 128 times?

Comment: I've edited my question to make it more clearly. My problem is that 128 ports is too many for input by hand. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR` as type for `data` instead, thus:

```
component MUX_1bit is
  port(
    data   : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(127 downto 0);
    sel    : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 DOWNTO 0);
    result : OUT STD_LOGIC);
end component;
```

Note that `select` is a reserved VHDL word, so this was changed to `sel` above.

For use of the component, then VHDL has flexibility, so the single bits or
ranges, or all can be used for data, like:

```
myMUX_1 : MUX_1bit port map(
  data   => dut_data,
  sel    => dut_sel,
  result => dut_result);

myMUX_2 : MUX_1bit port map(
  data(0)              => dut_data(0),
  data(1)              => dut_data(1),
  data(2)              => dut_data(2),
  data(7 downto 3)     => "10101",
  data(124 downto 8)   => (others => '0'),
  data(127 downto 125) => dut_data(127 downto 125),
  sel                  => dut_sel,
  result               => dut_result);
```

Having the data as a `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR` will also make the actual
implementation much easier, since `result` can be generated for a mux like:

```
result <= data(to_integer(unsigned(sel)));
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me edit and solve my question! If we extend each input/output width from std_logic(1bit) to std_logic_vector(7 downto 0), then I may define data as a  customized type "std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)" array. After that we still have something like result <= data(to_integer(unsigned(sel))). Am I right?

Comment: If you make `data` as array of `std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)` then you can still select through `data(to_integer(unsigned(sel)))`.